# Multilevel Menu in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a multilevel menu with css and jquery

see this : http://jsfiddle.net/YhgBw/

i am unable to take mouse to the second level.
as soon as i take mouse to the second level the script hides the full menu.

Script :

```
$('#bigmenu').hide();
$('#bigmenu_side').hide();
$('#mydiv').mouseenter(function (e) {
    $('#bigmenu').fadeIn(100);
});
$('#bigmenu').mouseleave(function (e) {
    var inFocus = $("#search_by_profile_id").is(":focus");
    if (!inFocus) {
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
    }
});

$('.bd_hover_change_color').mouseenter(function (e) {
    if (event.target.id == 'bd_menu_register') {
        $('#bigmenu_side').html("option A <br> option B <br> option C");
    }
    $('#bigmenu_side').show();
});
$('.bd_hover_change_color').mouseleave(function (e) {
    $('#bigmenu_side').html("");
    $('#bigmenu_side').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a logic problem in your code. You had to also make it so that the menu would not fade out when the mouse was over the `bigmenu_side`. To do this, set the class of `bigmenu_side` as `bd_hover_change_color` so that it would fulfill the requirements of the `$('.bd_hover_change_color').mouseenter` function.

Try this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YhgBw/24/

**UPDATE: Some problems with my previous fiddle link where the search and textfield became nonfunctional, updated it again for fully functional menu.**

Comment: I also noticed your "mouseenter" handler takes a parameter `e` but then accesses `event.target.id`. In order to get this statement to work correctly, either change the inside to `e.target.id` or the parameter to `event`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I tried it both ways and the menu worked the same. I don't think this really makes a difference does it? I could very well be wrong, I am not that experienced in jQuery.